# Accepting individual characters with basic.LineReceiver

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

I am using twisted's [basic.LineReceiver](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-8.2.0/twisted/protocols/basic.py#L186) to receive commands from the terminal as the program is running. This utility works very well for the most part as it works flawlessly with the rest of twisted. However, there are occasions that I require more advanced functionality such as receiving characters as they are typed in from the terminal. As an example, it would be really great to add in a method to find the UP character which outputs as `^[[A` on the display (or rather seen as `0x1B5B61` in the buffer). Adding functionality for accepting these special characters would be very useful to accept. Is there a pre-existing module provided by twisted to perform this functionality?

The code below is my test of intercepting characters before they enter the `dataReceived` method shown in [twisted's documentation to handle received data](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-8.2.0/twisted/protocols/basic.py#L211). The test scenerio is meant to provide a prompt (`-->` is the prompt I have chosen editable by modifying `self.prompt`). Inputing anything into the console should trigger the object to write out the hex equivalent to what was just typed. I have found that `dataReceived` is only called in my testing scenario when the user pressed the Return key (and not called when an individual character is typed). This renders by injection attempt useless since I require intercepting the message without requiring the user to type enter.

```
from os import linesep
from twisted.protocols import basic
from twisted.internet import reactor, stdio

class Test(basic.LineReceiver):
    delimiter = linesep

    def __init__(self):
        self.vk_up = '\x1B\x5B\x61'
        self.vk_down = '\x1B\x5B\x62'
        self.vk_left = '\x1B\x5B\x64'
        self.vk_right = '\x1B\x5B\x63'
        self.prompt = '-->'

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write(self.prompt)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        # This print statement below is my attempt to read what is passed into
        # this method.
        self.sendLine(self.hexify(data))
        basic.LineReceiver.dataReceived(self, data)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.run_cmd(line)

    def run_cmd(self, cmd):
        self.transport.write('{}{}{}'.format(cmd, Test.delimiter, self.prompt))

    def hexify(self, data, sep=' '):
        return sep.join(['{:02X}'.format(ord(x)) for x in data])

def main():
    stdio.StandardIO(Test())
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My hope is that there is a `twisted.protocols.advanced.LineReceiver`, but odds of that are slim. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `twisted.conch.insults` and there is some better code in [invective](https://github.com/exarkun/invective) that has some fancier input handling code that you can probably re-use somehow.